# storing a string and manipulating it in ASM language on ATmega168V (first homework assignment)

Tags: string, assembly, avr, memory-address

I am trying to store a string in memory, access that string and change the lower case letters to upper case and visa versa.  What I do not understand is how to reference the address of the string and ascii value at that address.  I believe I can figure the logic out, just having problems with data and address manipulation. How do I differentiate the two?  NOTE: This is a homework coding assignment.

Comment: what dialect of assembler? you will probably need to use `db`

Comment: ATmega168V   , I think this is what your asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. Flip the "32" bit with a `xor value,0x20` to toggle case.

On the Z80 assembler it would be something like

```
SRC:    DB      'Press A Key To Continue', 0; Our source string
DST:    DB      'Press A Key To Continue', 0; Where we will put our string. make sure its big enough so we don't over write our program.
;load MSG+0 to working regist
;flip the 32 bit
;move the working register to DST + 0
;load MSG+1 and repeat
```

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the string is different depending on if it's in the flash or RAM (I think that strings may be copied into RAM on boot, but I'm not positive). Given that this is a homework problem, though, you probably have direct access to the string in RAM. As @EnabrenTane points out you can just flip bit 5 of the char byte to change the case (read the excellent [Wikipedia ASCII page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii) to learn more about ASCII byte codes). So, if you needed to do this in C:

```
char the_string[6] = "foobar" // assuming string is created like this
int l = 6 * sizeof(char); // the length of the string

for(int i=0; i<l; i++) {
    char* c = the_string + i; // grab char[i] of the string
    *char = *char ^ 0x20; // flip the case
}
```

(I haven't tried compiling this so there may be errors)

For strings created like the one above the value stored in `the_string` is actually a pointer to the address of the first character. To find a specific character within that string you just add to the address. To manipulate the string you need to dereference your `char*` pointer and - in this example - store the value back into the same spot, overwriting the original value.